# netbeans autocomplete selectively displays hints based on phpdoc

Tags: netbeans, opencart

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and Netbeans 7.2.1

I'v got this project from github
https://github.com/opencart/opencart

Then I tried to add some variables in /upload/system/engine/controller.php via phpDoc like this

```
/**
 * @property Loader $load Description
 * @property Config $config Description
 * @property DB $db Desc
 */
```

It worked fine and in child controllers (for example upload/catalog/product/category.php) I saw hints when typed "$this->".

Then I got all "global" vars that can be in Registry, that contains parent controller and available via "$this->" and wrote them with code

echo ' * @property ' . get_class($value) . ' ' . $key . ' Description' . '
';

Then I copy result and paste it to phpdoc block. It was

```
 * @property Loader load Description
 * @property Config config Description
 * @property DB db Description
 * @property Url url Description
 * @property Log log Description
 * @property Request request Description
 * @property Response response Description
 * @property Cache cache Description
 * @property Session session Description
 * @property Language language Description
 * @property Document document Description
 * @property Customer customer Description
 * @property Affiliate affiliate Description
 * @property Currency currency Description
 * @property Tax tax Description
 * @property Weight weight Description
 * @property Length length Description
 * @property Cart cart Description
 * @property Encryption encryption Description
```

I was very hopeful opening child controller for testing autocomplete, but autocomplete didn't show me anything I added after typing "$this->".

I tried some combinations and noticed, that it works only when I'm using autocomplete when type "@pro" and then type "enter" button and then fill fields by typing "tab" to focus on next field. So even typing "@pro" and then typing "tab" and then manually write all other words don't make netbeans show autocomplete for that.

Does anyone know, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, i miss "$" symbol in

```
 * @property Log log Description
```

need

```
 * @property Log $log Description
```

Shame on me.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this script, that generate this block for entire project, including models:

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=11912

its only a file, put in root folder of yout opencart installation, run it, copy and paste on `"system/engine/controller.php"`